# Combination/Improvement of Formula using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to automate my google sheet, below is an example of what i am trying to achieve. I have achieved it using 10+ formulas across several columns. Is it possible to combine these formula or is there a better way to go about this?

[image: Example of Input/Output]

My current formulas (that work) are:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A:A)>=1, B:B&" "&"1"&"/"&A2:A,))` (If is used to remove column header)

I use this 10+ times across multiple columns for each case

```
=FILTER({A:A;B:B;C:C;D:D;E:E;F:F;G:G;H:H}, LEN({A:A;B:B;C:C;D:D;E:E;F:F;G:G;H:H}))
```

Used to combine columns together

```
=sort(AD:AD,1,true)
```

Used to sort alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=sort(ArrayFormula(transpose(split(textjoin("|", 1, if(len(iferror(split(rept(A2:A&"/", B2:B), "/"))), A2:A6&" "&column(1:1)&"/"&vlookup(split(rept(A2:A&"/", B2:B), "/"), A2:B, 2, 0),)), "|"))), 1, 1)
```

Change range to suit.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hey Bud, Thanks for posting this. It spits out the error "Array arguments to CONCAT are of different size. However MattKing has managed to solve the case mostly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You might also try this if your dataset is going to be very long:

[Here is a shared sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F0fXU0Oali8Bocz26Mxl9mpdtq3e_GkoIB4ShrekOQE/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({HLOOKUP({"X","Y"},{"X","Y";B2:C},SEQUENCE(MAX(C2:C)*COUNTA(B2:B),1,0)/MAX(C2:C)+2,0),MOD(SEQUENCE(MAX(C2:C)*COUNTA(B2:B),1,0),MAX(C2:C))+1},"select Col1,Col3,'/',Col2 where Col3<=Col2 order by Col1,Col3 label'/'''")),,4)," / ","/")))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for sending this through. Works well! just trying to get my head around the formula.Amazing shared Sheet. If the number of units is a total of two columns (Base + Extra) what would i substitute in for B2:C and C2:C?? Im slowly improving my understanding of formula! Thanks again

Comment: I duplicated the tab. New tab called Base+Extra is modified for your needs.  Whenever you share a sheet, try to make it as close to the original as possible. People often think they can "translate it back" to their real sheet, but it can get difficult :)  I'll be on the sheet for a bit if you want to understand something.

Comment: Thanks MattKing! I tried to modify it myself but didnt quite get it, I was on the right track though! I am enjoying the complexities of Excel/Sheet formula but it can be quite confusing sometimes